# Cannot extract correct element in chrome dev tools when using Python

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to access the dates from this site with css selectors but it is not allowing me. I keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/san- 
antonio/78205/daily-weather-forecast/351198")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
daily = soup.find(class_="content-module")
period_tags = daily.select(".date .dow")
periods = [pt.get_text() for pt in period_tags]
periods
```

I expect the output to give me each of the days on the webpage in list form

Comment: if you print soup there is something?

Comment: <title>Access Denied</title>....even adding     headers ={"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed the one User-Agent header. However, content is dynamically generated so your requests response html won't be the same as on web-page where javascript can run. You can extract the required info from a `script` tag in the response using regex and then parse with json parser

```
import requests, re , json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/san-%20antonio/78205/daily-weather-forecast/351198', headers=headers)
p = re.compile(r'var dailyForecast = (.*);')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
#print(data)
forecasts = {i['dow'] + ' - ' + i['date']:i['day'] for i in data}
print(forecasts)
dows  = [i['dow'] for i in data]
print(dows)
```